# When we should use "__attribute__((unused))" with Objective-C methods?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, attributes

Why and when we should use "unused" attribute?
Is there any guides on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a flag used simply to tell the compiler that you have a variable but that you aren't using it. It just prevents the compiler showing a warning. Using it also documents the code to show that it is intentional rather than a mistake.

Comment: What about methods? Are there any rules when to use "unused" attribute?

Comment: How do you mean? There are no rules about when you should use it really, it's just about warnings and documentation.

Comment: @Wain Is there any particular use case where we need to keep an unsused variable intentionally?

Comment: @iVishal the only 1 I can think of off the top of my head is a variable use for logging in a debug build which would cause a warning when the log is changed to a no-op in a release build...